C++. Нужно ли перегружать operator<< над basic_ostream вместо ostream?
Даю возможность своему классу писать в ostream через оператор <<.
friend static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const my_type& arg)

Но в принципе в будущем ведь может понадобится запись и в iostream. Да и в другие потоки, которые являются потомками basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char>>
Есть ли смысл сразу определить оператор:
friend static std::ostream& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char>>& stream, const my_type& arg)

?
Или это моветон и так не делают по каким-то причинам?

Смотрим тут и видим, что ostream — это то же самое, что и std::basic_ostream<char,char_traits<char>>. С учетом этого поясните, что вы хотите получить нового?

@Harry я не нового хочу получить. Я пытаюсь понять: Синоним ostream всегда будет работать как basic_ostream<char,char_traits>? Даже в контексте наследования?

Естественно. Это же одно и то же.

@Harry, хорошо. Спасибо.

И прошу отнестись с пониманием. Не просто в 41 год изучать плюсы, особенно, когда не кодил много лет, а когда кодил, то делал это в основном на Delphi )

Как правильно заметили, std::ostream - синоним std::basic_ostream<char>.
Можно зашаблонить <<, чтобы он принимал любой basic_ostream<...>, чтобы печатать например в "широкий" поток (с wchar_t символами). Насколько это полезно - другой вопрос.

Более интересная тема для размышлений - а нужны ли вообще ostream-ы в 202X, когда есть std::format (или libfmt). Возможно лучше учиться писать std::formatter-ы.

Спасибо. Обязательно ознакомлюсь.

Короче, не нужны эти лишние телодвижения. Так как ostream - это синоним basic_ostream<char,char_traits<char>>. И в любом контексте, включая наследование, ведёт себя так же.
Спасибо @Harry за пояснение в комментариях.
